# How to Remove LVM Physical Volume from (inaccessible) Server

Tags: partitioning, mount, live-usb, root, lvm

The goal is to remove the physical volume `/dev/sda` from this LVM setup (running on 16.04 server):

```
# pvdisplay

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdb3
VG Name               box-vg
PV Size               3.64 TiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              953611
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          953611

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda
VG Name               box-vg
PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 32.02 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              119227
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          119227

# vgdisplay

--- Volume group ---
VG Name               box-vg
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  6
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                2
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               4.09 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              1072838
Alloc PE / Size       1072838 / 4.09 TiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   

# lvdisplay

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/box-vg/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                box-vg
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                4.09 TiB
Current LE             1071844
Segments               3
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/box-vg/swap_1
LV Name                swap_1
VG Name                box-vg
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                3.88 GiB
Current LE             994
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:1
```

Straightforward, there are 2 PVs, 1 LV and 1 VG.

Trying `# pvmove /dev/sda` errors "No extents available for allocation" which (if I understand correctly) makes sense as there are no free physical extents on the only other physical volume to which to move it.

Attempts to free up extents (like `lvresize` or `lvreduce`) that use fsadm don't like to work on mounted drives -- saying it can't proceed with the mounted fs, or that the target is busy if it tries umount on its own.

While the physical machine itself is *not* at the bottom of a locked filing cabinet (stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying "Beware of the Leopard") it is difficult enough to access that I am hoping to find a solution that doesn't require a Live USB in order to unmount / (and additional downtime).

Am I painted into a corner and can't shrink a volume that's online?

Comment: Isn't data on that pv and you can't remove what is mounted or in use!

Comment: yes, if I understand correctly -- the single LV is mounted on root, so all the data (and the OS) are both on it and in use. Some commands seem to online (mounted) volume expansion but not reduction

Comment: You will have to use a livecd to first move that partition contents to another location then reduce the volume group. Make sure you backup I have tried this on vms and it usually doesn't go well!

Comment: I am assuming the process is to shrink `/dev/sdb3` so it has > 20K of Free PE (which is slightly more than what is currently used on `/dev/sda`) and _then_ `pvmove` (and `vgreduce` and `pvremove`) should execute? (assuming using the livecd here)

Comment: I think you're painted into a corner. I see three choices: 1) Plan the downtime, prepare the USB, access tools, travel, backups, tests, etc. so it's just one annoying afternoon...or 2) try to do it online, crash the system, and spend much longer in haste and panic, make mistakes, and miss a friend's birthday party....or 3) Take the opportunity to migrate to a whole new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to have the poor Lab server do is to:

- Perform a surgical operation on itself
- In the living room
- Without sterilised scalpels

So take the patient out of the lab, into the IT Room, boot from a USB and perform the operation in a clean operating room as:

- the physical volume is mounted
- contains the boot partition (so cannot be unmounted)
- split the LVM into:

  - swap
  - root
  - home

*at a minimum!*

Read the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) for even  more flexible future-proof options

And please?  Always leave at least 10% of the disk unparitioned so you can quickly add (part of) that 10% to any file system *live without downtime* in an emergency.